# RecyclerView add extra space on refresh

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented RecyclerView in my project,on my onPostExecute method I have added Decoration to my recyclerview but when refresh the Decoration is increasing.
my code :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    FeedsAdapter adapter = new FeedsAdapter(context, feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(20));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to remove decoration before adding new one.

Each time you call the `onPostExecute` method it will add new ItemDecoration to RecyclerView (thats why space is increasing).
Just try to remove it before adding, f.e. via `removeItemDecoration(referenceToItemDecoration)` or `removeItemDecorationAt(0)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create a new adapter every time you run the http call (or whatever the postExecute is for), you simply need to update the feedItems and call NotifyDataSetChanged().

right now you are recreating the adapter and adding vertical space every time you run postExecute, so maybe just add the adapter and the verticalSpace in oncreate, and then only update the dataset in postExecute and then notifyDataSetChanged